# Using biblatex-chicago with the authordate option on a file that uses headlesscite

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago

I usually use `biblatex-chicago` with the `notes` option, but I need to convert a document to `authordate` format. My document uses `\headlesscite` quite a lot, which results in an error because apparently when the `authordate` option is selected, `\headlesscite` is undefined.

How can I redefine `\headlesscite` so that it behaves like `\cite`?

I would like a solution that does not involve editing my document content (such as find/replace "headlesscite" with "cite") but only the preamble. (I tried to add `\newrobustcmd*{\headlesscite}{\cite}` to the preamble, but that doesn't work.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\headlesscite[10]{worman}
\end{document}
```

## desired output

> Worman 2002, 10

Comment: As a side note, it might make `biblatex-chicago` more robust if such a command-conversion were built into the package, making it possible to move seamlessly between `notes` and `authordate` without having to change anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't `\headlesscite` be more like `\cite*` instead of `\cite`?

Anyway,

```
\newrobustcmd*{\headlesscite}{\cite}
```

works absolutely fine, though I would probably just use

```
\newcommand*{\headlesscite}{\cite}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newrobustcmd*{\headlesscite}{\cite}

\begin{document}
\headlesscite[10]{worman}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Worman 2002, 10]

---

Regarding your side not in the comments, I don't disagree, but this is nothing we can do anything about. Please contact the author of `biblatex-chicago` about that. The many comments in the documentation about how some features came to be make me suspect he will be very happy to consider this question.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I realize now that I forgot to clear away all the helper files when testing it; I did, and it works perfectly, as you say. Thank you for pointing that out.